# php variable contains and html code contains a php variable

Tags: php, html

Is it possible?

here is the php code:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data['photo1']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
```

I want to include it in an html code that is also stored in a php variable like:

```
$var = "
 <div>
 the first code
 </div>";
echo $var;
```

How to do this?

Comment: Be specific of what you want so that others can contribute...

Comment: How to include the first php code in html ?

Comment: It looks like you need this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-50, if I understood you correctly ... I probably should write an answer, but that would be sleazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the first string in a variable instead of echoing it.

```
$img = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data['photo1']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
```

then you can substitute it into the other string:

```
$var = "
 <div>
 $img
 </div>";
echo $var;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like below:

```
<?php 
  $var = '<div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data['photo1']).'" height="100" width="100"/></div>';
  echo $var; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:-

```
$image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data['photo1']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
$var = "<div>".$image."</div>";
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something Like this

```
$var = "
 <div>
 <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64',".base64_encode($data['photo1'])." height='100' width='100'/>
 </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Albeit this is a bad method but why simply not,

```
$var = "<div>";
$var .= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data['photo1']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
$var.= "</div>";
```

then

```
echo $var;
```